# Prevent Kendogrid multi-tables (header and data) creation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Im using Kendogrid and it creates two tables, one for the header and other one for the data. 
My current problem is that when users scroll left/right the columns does not conserve the alignament; so, Im thinking that one posible solution is to force my Kendogrid don't create two but one table for all (header and values). Is this possible? There is an alternative?

---

[image]

Comment: Can you show us code that reproduces the issue? Maybe create a CodePen or DOJO.

Comment: You can check this image http://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/298869_Alignmnet.PNG?sfvrsn=0

Comment: Are you really using a KendoUI version from 6 years ago?

Comment: No, Im using another version (v2015.3.916), but still the same problem.

Comment: For me the fiddle works fine. The columns and header stay lined up...

Comment: Same for me the example render properly. But my browser renders the Header with div not a table only the rows are an actual table.

Comment: Have you compared between browser? Also Kendo no Longer support ie 9- if that's what you're running.

Comment: I put an image of the problem that I see in the fiddle

Comment: Im using Google Chrome last version

Comment: also look good in chrome for me: [link](http://imgur.com/a/QgSpa) could you have a plugin interfering?

Comment: I dont think its a plugin, but I promess it happens as I show in both images. Do you think its possible for the kendogrid renders in just one table?

Comment: Also I found this other example http://dojo.telerik.com/OFORe/4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142217/discussion-between-erick-langford-xenes-and-jonathan-bourassa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to prevent KendoGrid creation of two but one table for all (header and values); at least of course that you use a template.